# Adding 50 amp breaker to 90 amp subpanel

Tags: electrical

I have a 90 amp sub panel in the garage with a couple of empty slots. Am I able to add a 50 amp breaker for a 14-50 outlet without overloading the sub panel?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are two factors (basically) - physical space in the panel (which it appears you have) and actual usage of the panel. If you are going to use 50A for electric vehicle charging then you want to make sure your typical (peak is different) usage is no more than around 40A @ 240V -> 80A @ 120V (provided the legs are reasonably balanced). Absolutely no way to tell from this picture. 1 - Upload a full picture of the panel (this is chopped off at the top and sides; 2 - Upload a picture of the panel diagram (usually inside cover); 3 - What are the usual loads? Lights? Appliances? etc.

Comment: manassehkatz is right it looks like you have physical space, but you do need to confirm what's behind those spaces. A few panels out there use the same 24 space cover for 20 and 24 space guts. You make plans, take the cover off and you're back to square one. Real annoying.  Actual load is key to capacity, but my gut says that with that many branch circuits it is certain possible that panel doesn't have capacity.

Comment: The panel is a 125A panel, increasing feeder capacity could decrease likelihood you would overload the panel, could you describe wiring method, and size of wire?

Comment: I added a picture without the cover if you can tell what size feeder wire that is

Comment: All the circuits are running receptacles and lights. No appliances.

Comment: How many square feet of area does this panel serve?

Comment: The house is around 3200 sq ft

Comment: @JimmyWong -- are all the lighting/receptacle circuits for the house on this panel?  Or are there other lighting & receptacle circuits on other panels?

Answer (score 1):

Your panel has many "tandem" breakers... [read here on what those are, how those work and  how they relate to panel spaces](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/110151/what-is-a-tandem-breaker-aka-duplex-cheater-twin-double-stuff-etc).

### First, deal with  the fire-starters!

OK, there are at least three *Multi-Wire Branch Circuits* in here that are catastrophically miswired. They will overload neutral, putting  30A on a 15A wire.  "The last guy" did exactly the thing we warn people not to do: put MWBCs on tandems.

What's more, the installer violated the "handle-tie" rule of MWBCs, which would have prevented the blunder.

---

You will need two of (in order of preference) Eaton BQ215215, or BQC215215. Either one will do. You need two.

Pull the 8 wires off the bottom 4 left-side breakers.

Now, identify the three cables coming in that have  black-white-red.

Pick one cable.  Follow its black and red wires.  Stick them on the inner terminals of one of the breakers.

For the second cable, stick its black and red on the **outer** terminals of that same breaker.

For the third cable, stick its black and red on the inner terminals of the other breaker.

The two single-pole 15A circuits that are now dangling, go on the remaining breaker terminals.

Remove the bottom 4 breakers altogether, and snap these two quadplex in their place.

OK, so that's fixed. They have mandatory handle-ties, and they are *correctly phased* so you won't get a neutral fire.

### Install the 50A breaker.

Now, get a BQC2502120, or a BQC220250, in order of preference.   This has 50A in the middle and 20A outside.

Remove the 20A single breaker.  Replace it with the above breaker.

Put the existing 20A wire on the bottom terminal of the big BQC breaker.

Put the 50A load on the middle terminals.

Now you have 1 spare 20A breaker, and one full slot still free.

Plan on replacing that panel with something much bigger soon.  As expected, you ran out of spaces before you ran out of amps.

### Fix the markings on that panel.

They are a code violation for two reasons: First they specify rooms by *things only you know* like Karen's room, and second, they contradict each other.

Obviously someone rearranged this panel, and that's how the MWBCs got dangerously placed on tandems.

Also you are required to identify breakers by marking that will be obvious after you move out -- "northwest bedroom" not "playroom" and definitely not "child's name".

Just get some acetone or something and wipe off all that Sharpie (not that easy)... better yet, scrub it with a Scotchbrite pad (so the paint will stick), clean and dry it, then hit it with a can of Krylon. Great time to match it (roughly) to your walls - you are better off using an "oil paint" like is in spray cans, than a latex which doesn't work on machinery.

Number all the spaces the same way -- 1A-1B through 12A-12B is fine, or 1-24, whatever. If an AFCI breaker is sitting on 23 and 24, people will figure out what you mean when you say "23 NW Bedroom" or whatever.

Comment: Oh my goodness.  Thank you for the detailed information!! The scary part about this panel is that it was installed this way new by the tract home company, Lennar.  I wonder how it passed inspection??

As for the recommended breakers, what is the main difference between the 2 model numbers?

Lastly, for the 50amp breaker,  can I move the 20amp single breaker on the top right to the top left and get a new 50amp breaker to place on the top right?

Comment: The multi wire branch circuits need to be fixed before anything!!! That is a fire waiting to happen. + with the 2 open slots I might move things around but then the panel would be packed.

Comment: Thank you Ed. I have a electrician coming out today and will address the issue

Comment: @JimmyWong Read what I said to do with the 50A breaker... I am proposing you replace it with a quadplex which covers the 20A and 50A requirements.  That way you'll still have a space free in the end.  As far as being able to move it, I don't know if the wire is long enough.

Comment: The difference between the two breakers is one is in stock and the other is out of stock :) Seriously the less desirable one gives you common trip, which is not a requirement for MWBCs.

Comment: Harper.  Do you have a recommendation to get these breakers, that are in stock?

Comment: @Jimmy sorry I didn't think you would take me so literally.  COVID-19 has caused supply problems, so right now there are a lot of shortages.  Some breakers are hard to find, and it varies store to store.  I gave you two models that would work, so you would have an alternative in case the first one is not available.

Comment: LOL.  Thanks!!.  I will search online